# Is System.Collections a "namespace of the System namespace"?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Okay, so I've been reading a book on C# and .NET, and while learning about the DateTime structure and the following code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 10, 17);
```

I asked myself "why didn't I have to reference it at the top by writing `using System.DateTime`"?

So I realized that since DateTime is a structure, and the "using" keyword is used to reference types (type being a general term to refer to a member from the set {class, interface, structure, enumeration, delegate}), defined in a particular namespace (in this case, DateTime is of type structure from the System Namespace).

But I noticed that at the top of my file, the following using directives are found (they were put there automatically when I created my C# console application):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

I was wondering why the using directives that follow `using System` were necessary, when aren't they all under the System namespace and therefore they should already be referenced?

So I'm guessing it's because all the ones declared below it are **namespaces**, as opposed to a type from the set {class, interface, structure, enumeration, delegate}. But would it be wrong to refer to them as "namespaces OF (or belonging to) the namespace System," and if so, what is the reason that you must explicitly reference namespaces of a namespace instead of them being implicitly included under `using System`?

I hope my question was clear but if not, please let me know so I can edit it.

Comment: Just to clarify a misconception you seem to have: what follows the using in your examples are all namespaces. You would never have something like `using System.DateTime` because you never have classes (or structs) using this syntax. There are other ways to use `using` which are described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx . In terms of name resolution though structs and classes (and interfaces and anything else you can think of) all work much the same.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Internally, all .net types always have full type names;

```
System.DateTime
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>
System.Threading.Tasks.Task
```

what the 'usings' do is to let you refer 'invisibly' to everything before a '.' character. So when you write

```
DateTime
```

C# will try

```
System.DateTime
System.Collections.Generic.DateTime
System.Linq.DateTime
System.Text.DateTime
etc...
```

Since only one exists (`System.DateTime`) it's an unambiguous match, and C# knows what you're talking about.

If there were two matches, you'd get a compiler error about the ambiguity. So if there *were* a `System.Threading.Task.DateTime`, your program wouldn't compile.

All this sets the scene for the answer to your question. If

```
using System;
```

included everything below it, then it would be hard to ensure that things aren't ambiguous. For example, if you wanted to differentiate between two theoretical classes

```
System.WebPages.Button
System.Desktop.Button
```

then a plain old `using System` wouldn't play nice with `new Button()`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that if it *weren't* that way, you'd have no way of avoiding unwanted name collisions in certain circumstances.  For instance, if you had a type `Baz` in `Foo` namespace and a type `Baz` in `Foo.Bar` namespace, you'd always have to fully-qualify your types, e.g. `Foo.Baz` or `Foo.Bar.Baz`, in your code, which would make the `using` directives pointless.

Given the way it is, you only have to deal with name collisions if you actually have `using` directives for both namespaces that contain your type.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to have other using directives, e.g. if you wanted a List you could just declare in your code:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<String> listOfStrings = new System.Collections.Generic.List<String>;
```

To create a new List, but the using statement lets you simply declare it as:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new List<String>;
```

The reason you can't do the latter with only:

```
using System;
```

Is because there could be a class in System called List, as well as the List class in System.Collections.Generic. If so, when you create a new list object, how does it know which List class you're referring to?

So essentially they're used to prevent naming conflicts, and to enable programmers to group things into logically named groups, e.g. input and output related classes can be found in System.IO

Answer (score 1):

Create a using directive to use the types in a namespace without having to specify the namespace. A using directive does not give you access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify.

from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

The same thing happens when I am assigned namespaces cause of my folder structure like projectName\Code\DBFiles  if I do using Code; on one of my controllers it doesn't give me access classes in DBFiles that's why I set all my class name spaces to the root namespace.